# Как не выполнять команду в последний проход цикла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Есть цикл, в нем есть действие.
Это действие бы не хотелось выполнять в последний проход, только между.
К примеру:

```
from time import sleep


my_list = [1, 5, 161, 742] # просто случайные числа
print('start')

for i in my_list:
    print(i)
    sleep(3)
    
print('finish')
```

При выполнении этого цикла, перед выводом `finish` будет осуществлена задержка в 3 секунды.

Понятно, что можно добавить счетчик, и сравнивать его с количеством элементов:

```
from time import sleep

my_list = [1, 5, 161, 742]
my_len = len(my_list)
my_counter = 0

print('start')

for i in my_list:
    my_counter += 1
    print(i)
    if my_counter < my_len:
        sleep(3)
    
print('finish')
```

Но возможно существует какой то встроенный метод? Или просто более простое использование чего то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще переделать цикл и пропускать первую итерацию. Флажок `first` за это отвечает:

```
from time import sleep


my_array = [1, 5, 161, 742] # просто случайные числа
print('start')

first = True
for i in my_array:
    if first:
        first = False
    else:
        sleep(3)
    print(i)
    
print('finish')
```

Comment: А интересно выглядит.

Answer (score 3):

Уверен, что у вас что то не то с логикой задачи в целом.
В то же время, если мы говорим об итерировании списка или некоей последовательности, можно сделать такой вариант, который выглядит как извращение, но реализует именно то что вы хотите.

```
from time import sleep

my_array = [1, 5, 161, 742] # просто случайные числа
print('start')

for i in my_array[:-1]:
    print(i)
    sleep(3)
else:
    print(my_array[-1])

print('finish')
```

Такое решение немного быстрее чем с `enumerate`, т.к. в цикле не тратим время на проверки индекса.
И да, как бы мне хотелось, чтобы списки в пайтон не называли массивами )

Comment: Мне вот интересно, оно будет быстрее чем каждый цикл проверять флаг? Надо будет завтра почекать, хм...

Comment: Блин, сорян... Это у меня вроде еще со школы тянется, все подряд - `array`... Оно же `list`?

Comment: та не обращаете внимание на перфекционистов типа меня.
Просто в пайтоне есть модуль `array` для массивов. И - еще круче - `numpy`.   Второй поддерживает мат. операции с массивами.  Которые и быстрее и легче чем списки пайтона в лоб.

Это - если вам и правда нужны массивы и быстродействие

Comment: Как перестать ржать? На моем размере окна вывелось вот так: "И - еще круче - numpy. Второй поддерживает мат." - и конец строки. "Окей, гугл. Как материться на numpy?" xD PS там вообще не числа, а строка которую `.split()` и нужно подождать пока соседний поток обработает слово.

Comment: :-D  :-D  :-D  :-D

Answer (score 3):

Можно вообще ничего не считать в цикле и флаги не использовать. Просто напечатать первый элемент ДО цикла, последующие  - в цикле, и перед каждым - пауза.

```
from time import sleep

my_list = [1, 5, 161, 742]
print('start')
if my_list:
    print(my_list[0])
    for i in my_list[1:]:
        sleep(3)
        print('Пауза...') # для наглядности
        print(i)
print('finish')
```

```
start
1
Пауза...
5
Пауза...
161
Пауза...
742
finish
```

Comment: Тоже можно, спасибо.

Comment: Можно. Я такой способ не люблю лично, когда конструкцию ради которой весь цикл нужно повторять два раза )

Answer (score 2):

```
from time import sleep


my_list = [1, 5, 161, 742] # просто случайные числа
seconds = [3 for __ in my_list[:-1]] + [0]            # [3, 3, 3, 0]

print('start')

for el, sec in zip(my_list, seconds):
    print(el)
    sleep(sec)
    
print('finish')
```

Т.е. для последнего перехода циклом используем в функции `sleep()` задержку `0` секунд.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так - на мой вкус красиво:

```
for i,x in enumerate(smth):
  if i: sleep(3)
  print(x)
```

Впрочем, варианты без проверки условий и без emumerate, наверное, будут быстрее.

Comment: Кстати да, так понятнее гораздо ))  И нет, на скорость это не сильно повлияет, проверка числа на ноль очень быстрая, и `enumerate` не очень много оверхеда даёт. Тем более в сравнении с 3 секундами сна. P.S. Не пишите тело `if` в той же строке, в питоне так нежелательно писать )

Answer (score 1):

Такого встроенного метода нету, но можно использовать функцию `enumerate()` для получения индекса

Comment: Ага, значит вместо `my_counter` я делаю `enumerate(my_array)` и дальше уже пляшу от индекса. Можно, да.

Comment: Да, именно так. Вы получаете значения (индекс, элемент)`для каждого элемента в my_array

Comment: Гхм, это было бы лучше оформить как комментарий. В ответах обычно пишут код. Формально не придерешься, но писать такие ответы — моветон. Накопите еще пяток баллов репы и комментируйте. А такими ответами разве что минусы словите.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` можно использовать для более простой проверки:

```py
for flag, i in enumerate(my_list, 1 - len(my_list)):
    print(i)
    if flag:
        sleep(3)
```

На последней итерации `flag` будет равен нулю и проверка не пройдёт, `sleep` будет пропущен.

Comment: Слооооооожно)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, код короче, но стоп-условие не очевидное )

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что всем понравится, но достаточно лаконично:

```
from time import sleep

my_list = [1, 5, 161, 742]  # просто случайные числа
print('start')

for i in my_list:
    print(i)
    if not i == my_list[len(my_list) - 1]:
        print("...")
        sleep(3)

print('finish')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]